# Upgrade 14.04 to 16.04 on laptop, boots to command line, won't accept input

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

The install took 7 hours+, and after, fsck was forced, found probably thousands of bad inodes, at least hundreds, which I told it to repair.

BTW, I had told it to install gdm, not gdm3 or the light one.

When it booted, the Ubuntu screen with the 5 dots appears for a bit,
then it goes to command line
login:

But it accepts no input from the keyboard. Nothing appears.

I can get into maintenance mode via grub, but I really don't know
what to do next.  I can't apt-get. No internet at this point.

Ideas? 
Thanks.

Comment: I was able to login on that command line, ran ppg-purge ppa:ubuntu-toochain-r/test  then dpkg --configure - a  and then apt-get install -f

Comment: Sorry - never used this comment before... then I did startx, and from terminal window,  firefox & so I could get here. There are no menu or task bars ....  and the mouse pointer is a big X instead of an arrow.  Is it thegdm?

Comment: Anyone know how to run something that verifies or gives information on the install? I don't have any task or menu bars, can only open a terminal and run commands from the command line...   or would you point me to a way to do a re-install?

Answer (score 0):

Try booting from a Ubuntu live USB or optical disk.
This will not fix the problem but may allow you to get enough info on what is going on to effect a repair.  I would also attempt to run test software to see the condition of the disk.  You should be able to do this from the live system.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I created the bootable usb, and did a full re-install (took hours). 
Then, had to do updates to 16.04.1 (more hours!).  The update software asked questions in the old style tab-underline-enter for answers, which surprised me.

It isn't really very clear what the problem was. I had tried to set it to use 
gdm, but now am using Unity... which I'm not fond of. I'm old-school linux.

I have no sound now, either.

And it is noticeably slower. Top shows nothing unusual. 
Hard drive is better, fsck took care of it.

Marking this as answered, and will do the research for the other problems.